# Deriving variance of non-central chi-square

Tags: statistics

$\newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname{Var}}$Let $X \sim \chi^2_k(\lambda)$ be a non-central chi-square random variable. $\Var(X)$ is given in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution) as $2(k + 2\lambda)$ where $k$ is the degrees of freedom and $\lambda$ is the centrality parameter. Can someone point me to a derivation of this fact?

**My attempt of proof:**

By definition, $X = \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i^2$ where we have independent $Y_i \sim N(\mu_i, I)$. Define $\lambda = \sum_{i=1}^k \mu_i^2.$ Since [we know that](https://www.quora.com/How-would-you-prove-that-Kurtosis-is-zero-just-for-the-normal-distribution) $E(Y^4) = 3$,
\begin{align*}
\Var(X)
&= \Var\left(\sum_{i=1}^nY_i^2\right) = \sum_{i=1}^n \Var(Y_i^2) = \sum_{i=1}^n\Big[E(Y_i^4) - E(Y_i^2)^2\Big]\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n\Big[3 - (\Var Y_i + E(Y_i)^2)^2\Big] = \sum_{i=1}^n \Big[ 3 - (1 + \mu_i^2)^2\Big] \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n\Big[2 - 2\mu_i^2 - \mu_i^4\Big]\\
&= 2k - 2\lambda - \sum_{i=1}^n\mu_i^4
\end{align*}

But then I get stuck.

Comment: We do not know that $E(Y^4) = 3.$ We know that $E((X_i-\mu_i)^4) = 3$ for each $i.$ $E(Y^4) = 3$ does not make sense... imagine each $\mu_i=10000000$ or something.

Comment: Sorry I accidentally switched $X$ and $Y$... was thinking too long. Does it make sense now?

Comment: I am simply stating that the kurtosis of a normal random variable is 3.

Comment: The kurtosis is $E((Y_i-\mu_i))^4,$ not $E(Y_i^4).$ (Actually, it's divided by $\sigma_i^4$ but that's one here.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $$ Var \left(\sum_i X_i^2\right) = \sum_i Var(X_i^2) = \sum_i E(X_i^4)-E(X_i^2)^2.$$

First, we know that $E(X_i^2) = Var(X_i) + E(X_i)^2 = 1+\mu_i^2.$

To get $E(X_i^4)$, we can take what we know about central moments. First off, $$0 = E((X_i-\mu_i)^3) = E(X_i^3) - 3 E(X_i^2)\mu_i +3\mu_i^2 E(X_i) -\mu_i^3\\ = E(X_i^3) -3(1+\mu_i^2)\mu_i + 3\mu_i^3-\mu_i^3 \\= E(X_i^3)-3\mu_i-\mu_i^3$$ so $$ E(X_i^3) = \mu_i(3+\mu_i^2).$$

And then from the kurtosis, since $\sigma_i=1,$ we have $$ 3 = E((X_i-\mu_i)^4) = E(X_i^4) -4E(X_i^3)\mu_i + 6 E(X_i^2)\mu_i^2-4E(X_i)\mu_i^3 + \mu_i^4 \\ =E(X_i^4) -4\mu_i^2(3+\mu_i^2) +6(1+\mu_i^2)\mu_i^2 -4\mu_i^4+\mu_i^4\\=E(X_i^4)-6\mu_i^2 -\mu_i^4$$ so $$E(X_i^4) = \mu_i^4 +6\mu_i^2 +3.$$

Putting it all together $$ Var\left(\sum_i X_i^2\right)= \sum_i E(X_i^4)-E(X_i^2)^2 \\=\sum_i (\mu_i^4+6\mu_i^2+3) - (1+\mu_i^2)^2\\=\sum_i4\mu_i^2+2 = 4\lambda + 2k.$$

Comment: Thank you for writing this down! It was very helpful. I tried to replicate this but now with a variance unequal to 1 but to sigma^2 lets say.
Following these steps I arrived at a conclusion, which does not coincide with my numerical measurements... I have done the derivation twice, so I am quite sure I did not make a mistake. 
Could it be that I missed a hidden assumption? Is there a logical reason why I cant plug in 1 = sigma ^2 for the variance and follow these steps?

Comment: to clarify some more: when I set the noise in my simulation equal to 1, my formula does coincide with what you have derived. So that makes me certain I atleast did something right

Comment: @zwep there shouldn’t be any problem with that.  More simply, you can fill in the missing factors of $\sigma^2$ in the final result by dimensional analysis… no re-calculation required.

Comment: For others, my calculations gave: $3k + \sum_i 4 \mu_i^2 \sigma_i ^2 - \sigma_i ^ 4$. With some setting for mu and sigma, my calculations are within 6\% of each other. While if the noise dominates, then I can be off by about 40\%.

Comment: @zwep You need to think in  terms of dimensional analysis. That 3k term makes no sense... it has the wrong units. Since in the $\sigma_i^2=1$ case we have $Var(X_i^2) = 4\mu_i^2+2,$ that means that for general $\sigma_i^2,$ we have $Var(X_i^2) = 4\mu_i^2\sigma_i^2+2\sigma_i^4.$ Presumably what you did was say $E((X_i-\mu_i)^4)=3$, rather than $E((X_i-\mu_i)^4/\sigma_i^4) = 3.$

Comment: Thanks for helping me out! My current answer is: $\sum_i 4 \sigma_i ^2 \mu_i ^2 + 2 \sigma_i ^4$. This does coincide with my numerical experiments, really happy with this :)